# URLS and views in DJANGO

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm not sure exactly how to word this, but here goes. I have several views that my urls.py doesn't seem to get to at all, and I don't know why. I'm new to django and admit to being a bit perplexed as to how some of it works.

In my template I have:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/project/{{project.slug}}/tickets/create">Create Ticket</a></li>
    <li><a href="/project/{{ project.slug }}/tickets/edit">Edit Ticket</a></li>
    <li><a href="/project/{{ project.slug }}/tickets/delete">Delete Ticket</a></li>
</ul>
```

In my urls.py:

```
(r'^ticket/(?P<ticket_id>\d+)$', views.editTicket),
(r'^(?P<project_slug>[^\.^/]+)/tickets/create$', views.createTicket),
(r'^(?P<project_slug>[^\.^/]+)/tickets/(?P<ticket_id>\d+)$', views.deleteTicket),
```

In my views.py:

```
def createTicket(request, project_slug):
    project = Project.objects.get(slug=project_slug)
    form = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        t = Ticket(created_by=request.user, assigned_to=request.user)
        form = TicketCreateForm(request.POST, instance=t)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = Comment(user=request.user, body=request.POST.get("description", ""), subject="")
            comment.save()
            t.description = comment
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/project/ticket/%d" % t.pk)
    else:
        form = TicketCreateForm(instance=Ticket(project=project, assigned_to=request.user))
    payload = { 'project':project, 'form':form }
    return render(request, 'project/ticket_add.html', payload)

def editTicket(request, ticket_id):
    ticket = Ticket.objects.get(pk=ticket_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TicketCreateForm(request.POST, instance=ticket)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.setComment(Comment(parent=ticket.description, user=request.user, body=request.POST.get("comment", " ")))
            form.save()
    form = TicketCreateForm(instance=ticket)
    payload = { 'project':ticket.project, 'ticket':ticket, 'ticket_form':form }
    return render(request, 'project/ticket.html', payload)

def deleteTicket(request, ticket_id):
    ticket = Ticket.objects.get(pk=ticket_id)
    ticket.delete()
    redirect_to = 'project/tickets.html'
    return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)

def editTicket(request, ticket_id):
    ticket = Ticket.objects.get(pk=ticket_id) 
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        form = TicketCreateForm(request.POST, instance=ticket) 
        if form.is_valid(): 
            form.setComment(Comment(parent=ticket.description, user=request.user, body=request.POST.get("comment", " "))) 
            form.save()
    form = TicketCreateForm(instance=ticket) 
    payload = { 'project':ticket.project, 'ticket':ticket, 'ticket_form':form }
    return render(request, 'project/ticket.html', payload)
```

What am I doing wrong here? Can anyone help?

Comment: " I have several views that my urls.py doesn't seem to get to at all". How do you mean? What actions are you taking, and what errors/unexpected behaviour do you get?

Comment: Looks pretty close to me, I'd review the tutorials (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/) on the Django website. If you posted specific error messages, that may help. I think you're pretty close though. Also the django irc channel on freenode is really really good.

Comment: Doc, thank you. I'm not getting any errors, unfortunately. Instead I have a whole lot of "nothing" going on where things should be.

Comment: Paul, I'm not getting any errors- which is part of the problem because it's not leading me to anywhere to look for what's wrong. What is happening is that when I run this, and hit a link that should bring up a certain view it doesn't. The page basically reloads itself and doesn't do anything. I'm not getting any errors related to the urls or code.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues here,

First, unless you have modified the related settings, it is best to add a / to the end of your url's, especially since you are including $ in your URL regexps, and django may redirect to add a final slash to your address.

Second, your `deleteTicket` function, is taking `request` and `ticket_id` as arguments, while it needs 3 according to your regexp, `project_slug` is missing.

3rd, `<a href="/project/{{ project.slug }}/tickets/delete">Delete Ticket</a>` simply won't match `(r'^(?P<project_slug>[^\.^/]+)/tickets/(?P<ticket_id>\d+)$', views.deleteTicket),`, since there is no sign of a `ticket_id`.

4th (and unrelated to the matching issue), you are deleting an object through an HTTP GET request which may not be a good idea (e.g, it may be cached or search engines may try to hit it). Also calling `Ticket.objects.get(pk=ticket_id)` might raise an exception, try `get_object_or_404(Ticket, pk=ticket_id)` which is more likely to do what you want. It is in `from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404`.

If this doesn't work out, try viewing the HTML source of that shows up in the template (with values placed instead of `{{project.slug}}`) so further inspection can be carried out.

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Thank you Darioush... I tried something to purposely throw an error so I could try to find out what is going on... Here is what happened... I clicked a link that SHOULD have invoked the "delete view" however, instead of that I got an error from a view I am not even trying to work with... I am confused as to why this happened?

Comment: You need to adhere to the 1st and 3rd advise. If you have already done that, what is the error?

Comment: DoesNotExist at /project/test-project1/tickets/delete  
    from comment.models import Comment

    from .models import *

    from .forms import *

    from pages import *

    from svnrepos import *

    def showProject(request, project_slug):

     project = Project.objects.get(slug=project_slug)

    ...

     tickets = Ticket.objects.filter(project=project)

     payload = { 'project':project, 'tickets':tickets }

     return render(request, 'project/project.html', payload)

    def editProject(request, project_slug):
        project = Project.objects.get(slug=project_slug)

Comment: For the first one, are you saying to add that / at the end of each url in the urls.py? When I do that i get an error that an expression is expected.

Comment: All I can say with this information is either it is because you are importing a module that doesn't exist (maybe svnrepos?)
Or it is that you haven't changed `deleteTicket` to `deleteTicket(request, project_slug, ticket_id)`.

Comment: I did that, and got this: deleteTicket() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Comment: I've changed the deleteTicket to: def deleteTicket(request, ticket_id):
    get_object_or_404(Ticket, pk=ticket_id)
    ticket.delete()
    redirect_to = 'project/tickets.html'
    return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)  and now when I run it I am getting deleteTicket() got an unexpected keyword argument 'project_slug' which is expected because {{project_slug}} is still in the url. However when i take that out and do this: (r'^tickets/delete$', views.deleteTicket), I am right back where I started. :( I've tried to follow all the suggestions but I seem to be going in circles.

Comment: The does not exist error is because you are calling `.get(pk=...)` on for some record that doesn't exist in your DB.